# Creating a python script that will take a text file search for a certain key and copy number to a new file

Tags: python, file

i'm looking for advice on how to create a script that will search a file for a key word.

My text file looks like this

```
1,1467800,968.00,957.00,8850,1005,963,546,950,8.00,
0.00,202149.00,12,
1,146928,1005,97995.00,979.00,967.000,824,955,826,
1,147,957.00,883.00,
```

it's from a Bluetooth device that I was having trouble with them talking over each other my solution was to make one device send a float the other send an int. I'm now trying to separate the numbers, and place them in 2 separate text documents. are there any functions I can do to make this project easier?

This is my current code that just takes in my text file

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
f1 = open("output.txt","w")
text = ""
for line in f:
  text = line
  text = text.rstrip("\n")
  print(text)
f1.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Please describe which is the output you want to obtain. You mention two files but do not know which kind of criteria you want to apply to put information in each file. It seems you want number with decimal separator to go to one file, and the rest to the other... is that right? Are line breaks meaningful at all? Please describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = text.split(",")
ints, floats = []
for item in my list: 
    if '.' in item: #(if float)
        floats.append(float(item))
    else:
        ints.append(int(item))
```

Explanation:
Split funtion converts text into a list by splitting it into elements using given key. (comma in this case)

Then you can write them into two different documents. For the sake of simplicity I divided them into two other lists which you can use to write a new file.

Answer (score 0):

**If your floats are not all actually integers**, you can use the is_integer function of float and list comprehensions:

```
with open('your_file') as fd:
    numbers = fd.read().split(',')
    floats = [float(num) for num in numbers if not float(num).is_integer()]
    integers = [float(num) for num in numbers if float(num).is_integer()]
```

You can also convert the numbers to a set after getting the floats and substract it from the original numbers list.

**Otherwise:**

```
with open('your_file') as fd:
    numbers = fd.read().split(',')
    floats = [float(num) for num in numbers if '.' in num]
    integers = [float(num) for num in numbers if float(num).is_integer()]
```